# Wordpress Debian Server Shows php version 8.2 But Wordress info page shows earlier version

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress website version shows
php -v
PHP 8.2.7 (cli) (built: Jun  9 2023 07:37:35) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.7, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v8.2.7, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

However, the WordPress info page shows:
PHP version 7.4.33 (Supports 64bit values)

The question is how can I have the WordPress run on the latest php version?

Answer (score 0):

CLI version of PHP has nothing to do with the web version. Install and configure your webserver to use the desired version:

See here: https://superuser.com/questions/969861/phpinfo-and-php-v-shows-different-version-of-php.